# White phial: "You're not supposed to be in here"

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I am trying to start the White Phial quest, but both Quintus and Nurelion just say "you're not supposed to be in here" no matter what time of day I visit their shop.  Did it hurt anything when I picked up the unmelting snow from the top of the Throat of the World before visiting the White Phial?

Answer (score 2):

Oddly enough, I just did the "White Phial" quest today. The Unmelting Snow (as you probably know) is used for the "Reapiring the Phial" quest that comes after you finished the White Phial quest. Try storing the Unmelting Snow in a chest or something and then talking to Nurelion and Quentis.